# Mcrypt Extension for Mojave's PHP 7.1 not using brew

Tags: mojave, php

I'm using macOS Mojave (10.14.3) and it already has apache2 and php 7.1 which are [setup](https://medium.com/@soufianerafik/setting-up-php-7-on-macos-high-sierra-714594eadbbe).
I want mcrypt installed but all the info on the internet including [this](https://gist.github.com/idleberg/24479f34dc5007e50d47) uses brew. I didn't install php using brew so I am looking for a solution to install mcrypt using a non-brew method. Is this possible ?
I have pear - https://jasonmccreary.me/articles/install-pear-pecl-mac-os-x/
I found a solution for Ubuntu's PHP 7.2 : https://lukasmestan.com/install-mcrypt-extension-in-php7-2/

Comment: Check out this guy's solution. You should be able to use the second half or so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51067784/850782

Comment: But this again uses Brew. I have PHP 7.1 installed by default in Mojave.

Comment: Sorry, I had missed that. What I was looking at was this part: `sudo /usr/local/opt/php/bin/pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1`. `pecl` is now the recommended way to install `mcrypt`, but it may not be included in Mojave. PEAR does include pecl. https://jasonmccreary.me/articles/install-pear-pecl-mac-os-x/ recommends `curl -O http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar`, `sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar`. Once PEAR is configured, run `pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1`